# Одно значение для нескольких ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict, value

```
info_dict = {}
with open('xx.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        key, value= line.strip().split(':')
        info_dict[key] = value
```

Есть такой код. Представим что есть несколько, почти одинаковых, ключей, для которых должно быть одно значение как это можно сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, вы же получаете ключи и значения из файла, вам нужно заменить полученные значения на другие для похожих ключей? Также непонятно на сколько "похожими" должны быть ключи, чтоб значения для них были одинаковые

Comment: вот например есть ключ город, я его просклоняю и у этого ключа будет 9 версий (если склонять  с помощью pymorph3) как сделать так чтобы у всех этих ключей было одно и тоже значение

Comment: Всем девяти версиям этого ключа присвоить одно и тоже значение.

Comment: Хранить в словаре не склонения а только именительный падеж. Перед обращением к словарю преобразовывать склонение к именительному падежу.

Comment: Можно создать список из кортежей в которых хранятся пары из списка схожих слов и значений для этой группы слов, затем проходясь по списку кортежей и словарю, смотреть, если ключ словаря входит список, являющийся первым элементом кортежа, то присваивать этому ключу значение равное второму элементу кортежа(значение одинаковое для группы слов). Но это если что не самое эффективное решение, тк тут 2 цикла будет.

Comment: step1709, можно пример такого кода?

Comment: @Лев сейчас в ответ пример кода закину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это пример кода, который может решить проблему, но для этого нужно знать все похожие ключи(полагаю с этим проблем не будет их можно получить с помощью того же `pymorph3`), которые попадают в группу с одинаковым значением и знать, какое значение для этих ключей. В примере словарь из пар ключ-название числа и значение-значение числа, превращается в словарь из пар ключ-название числа и значение-количества цифр в числе.

```
nums = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'eleven': 11, 'twelve': 12, 'thirteen': 13} #заменим значение числа на длинну числа(1 для однозначных, 2 для двузначных)
lenth = [(['one', 'two', 'three'], 1), (['eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen'], 2)] #список кортежей в котором первый элемент-список целевых ключей, второй элемент значение для этих ключей
for i in lenth:
    for k, v in nums.items():
        if k in i[0]:
            nums[k] = i[1]
print(nums) # результат {'one': 1, 'two': 1, 'three': 1, 'eleven': 2, 'twelve': 2, 'thirteen': 2}
```

В целом вам нужно создать список кортежей, в которых будет храниться 2 элемента(список похожих ключей и одно значение для этих ключей), а затем запустить двойной цикл. В примере используется словарь `nums`, у вас это будет словарь `info_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```py
info_dict = {}

with open('xx.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')

        # проверяем, если ключ уже существует в info_dict
        if key in info_dict:
            # если ключ уже существует
            if type(info_dict[key]) == str:
                # ...и он не является массивом
                # то мы просто делаем значение с ключом key массивом
                info_dict[key] = [info_dict[key]]

            # а если значение уже является массивом
            # добавляем в этот массив ещё одно значение
            info_dict[key].append(value)

            # и переходим к следующей итерации, чтобы значение (массив) не перезаписалось строкой
            continue

        # если не добавлять выше continue, то выполнится эта строка
        info_dict[key] = value # ...и перезапишет массив

print(info_dict)
```

Код объяснил в комментариях.

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Чего????

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ааа блин )

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy зачем?

Comment: так мне удалять ответ?